# WKHTMLTOPDF can't find BrowserUpdate.exe

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I have wkhtmltopdf working in ubuntu with Laravel-Snappy, it had been working all correct and suddenly I am getting this error that says:

Error opening /tmp/BrowserUpdate.exe: No such file or directory

I can't find any documentation about that. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my view, I had an iframe with browserupdate.exe no problem with wkhtmltopdf, when I cleared the cache from my view it worked.